# How to limit the number of multiple / parallel builds in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I don't know how to limit the number of concurrently running builds in Azure Pipelines.
For instance when creating more than one PR on GitHub at the same time, I want that only one build (for one PR) at the same time is running.

I checked the [YAML schema reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema) but couldn't find information regarding *parallel builds* only regarding *parallel jobs* which is not the same thing.

Comment: Hosted or OnPrem agent do one job at a time, you can configure just to have one agent so the builds will be run one at a time

Comment: @AlexandrMihalciuc Assume we have a scenario with a [matrix strategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#strategies) where I want several agents to run in parallel and where over time the number of parallel jobs can vary (due to platforms or versions being added) and I don't want to have an implicit dependency on such a setting. Or we have `Job1` and dependant `Job2` and `Job3`. Then after `Job1` completed I'd want the other two jobs to run in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible for manually triggered builds. However, for CI builds, you can use "CI Triggers" to solve this -

Add below snippet should do the job -

```
trigger:
  batch: true  # This is the change you need
  branches:
    include:
    - <branch-name>
```

*"If you set **batch to true**, when a pipeline is running, the system waits until the run is completed, then starts another run with all changes that have not yet been built"*

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Answer (score 0):

> I want that only one build (for one PR) at the same time is running.

For this demand ,I think Alexandr Mihalciuc's comment could meet your need. You can configure to make only one agent available.

But if you want to run two jobs in parallel on the basis of satisfying the above condition, I think this is not feasible. Because in order to meet only run one build, only one agent is available at this time, and an agent cannot do parallel jobs.